# How to batch make folders based off of text file with sequential number

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a text file something like below.

```
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

I also made a batch file that makes folders from a text file but how can I add sequential number to each folder name (probably with leading zero)?

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (%1) do (
  md "%%f"
)
```

I want the result something like this:

```
foo_001
bar_002
baz_003
qux_004
```

best regards.

Comment: Just so we are clear you are passing the file name to the batch file?

Comment: yes. I made a batch file and a text file then drag 'n drop to the batch file to make folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you basically have two options. Create a counter variable and increment inside the `FOR` command.  Or you can use the `FINDSTR` command to create the numbers which is what I have chosen to do.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /N "^" "%~1"') do (
    set num=000%%G
    md "%%H_!num:~-4!"
)
```

Comment: Sorry, i was at the middle of writing comment, I accidentally hit Add Comment. 
I wanted to add I don't fully understand the code (but that leaves me a good learning opportunity :) ) 
And no space between `enabledelayed` and `expansion`, right?
@Squashman

Answer (score 0):

Just to show there is at least a 3rd way using a counting loop and reading input from file:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\25\SO_52980091.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

<SO_52980091.txt (
  For /l %%A in (1001,1,1999) do (
        Set /p "Input="
        if not defined Input goto :Eof
        Set Num=%%A
        MD "!Input!_!Num:~-3!"
        Set "Input="
  )
)
```

I attest Squashmans batch to be more elegant/shorter.